# Pytorch: Increase indice of tensor to specific size

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor of `[20, 3, 32, 32]`
I want to increase the `3` to `64` (`[20,64,32,32]`, where `20` is the batch size). I tried the repeat function. But that only gives me `63` or `66`, because with repeat you can only tile (multiply) indices.
How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeat using [`torch.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat) and then filter with indices.

```py
t = torch.rand(20,3,32,32)
t.shape
torch.Size([20, 3, 32, 32])

t = t.repeat(1,22,1,1)[:,:-2,:,:]
t.shape
torch.Size([20, 64, 32, 32])
```